# Java programming requirements

Tags: java, ide, jakarta-ee

I am a C# programmer. I want to learn Java to implement my windows application. But I don't know what IDE and what tools can help me.

Please help me to choose best platform and IDE and other tools.

**Edit:**
Thank You For Your Helping. And What is Best Ebooks and UserGuids to Learn java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, download the java jdk.

http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp

Later, install an IDE. I suggest you to use Eclipse, I like it:
http://www.eclipse.org/

Another one very used is Netbeans:
http://netbeans.org/

Have Fun!

Comment: The netbeans Ide has a very good tools to build windows applications. Eclipse has one too, but I prefer netbeans for windows application.

Comment: The best user guide is to use Google. Or buy some book but you already know how to program in a language that is like Java, so you shouldn't have too much problems.

Comment: The Eclipse Visual Editor Project wasn't supported from 3.3's release in June 2007 through late 2009.  Furthermore, the latest release of VEP doesn't work with Eclipse 3.5 for J2EE due to dependency conflicts.

Answer (score 7):

There are really three big IDE's that people use:

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)

[Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html) (my personal favorite)

The online [Java Tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/) are a great place to start learning the language.

Answer (score 5):

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) or [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org) will be your best bet for an IDE (in my options)

Set up [Git](http://git-scm.com) for source control

Use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage your builds (if you're getting that complex)

Answer (score 1):

There's a short tutorial along with a great comparison table [here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/codesharp/java-for-c-developers-21248).  It's a Java tutorial aimed at C# developers.

Answer (score 1):

Java is very close to C# you don't need more than [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) (Actually I prefer it more than [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/)) and search for any syntax you want in the [Java documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/)

Answer (score 1):

JDK

- First you need to download Java
  development kit(J2SE 6)  from Sun's
  website

IDEs

- eclipse or netbeans

Books

- If you are planning to use Swing for
  windows application - you may read
  sun's tutorial
  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/
- Or if youa re a serious Java learner
  get the Thinking in Java book from
  here
  http://www.odioworks.com/46-Bruce_Eckel%27s_Free_Electronic_Books.html

By the way, welcome to Java's world :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Java World. You can either use Swing or SWT for windows form like development. Here is a good link to get started with SWT http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3330861/SWT-Programming-with-Eclipse.htm .

On top of what the other user's have already recommended, I would suggest getting familiarized with a J2EE container. It will come in handy in the future. Here is a link on what it [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container). JBOSS container is free and a pretty good one to use in my opinion. You can download it [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/).

Answer (score 1):

For Windows app with SWT / AWT gui you should know there are plugins for IDE that help you to create your gui. Check for exemple Matisse for NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have Eclipse up and running, you should look at the [Visual Editor Project](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/) plugin at Eclipse for developing windows applications. Hand-coding all of the SWT stuff is a big pain and hence the plugin will help.

Answer (score 1):

netbensIDE will help u